# Why am I unable to connect to my apache 2.2 server when the port is forwarded, the service is running and I am able to connect via loopback?

Tags: networking, windows-7, apache-2.2

So I decided to get into systems administration by setting up as many daemons/services as possible on my home PC. UnrealIRCd, FileZilla Server and 2 Minecraft servers work perfectly; remotely and within the subnet. however, my Apache 2.2 HTTPd is not working outside of loopback. I checked my port forwarding a thousand times on the NAT device, the PortForward.com port checker tool reports that the port is open (port 2000 to be exact).
2 remote nmap scans:

```
$ nmap -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v hostname
$ nmap -sS -sU -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v hostname
```

didn't show the port as being unfiltered or open though. It did show all other ports forwarded into the subnet.

I'm not sure if it's an Apache configuration problem, a host problem or a NAT problem
Apache runs fine through loopback, I get no errors in the logs.

I'm running Apache HTTPd 2.2.17 in Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1 behind a Netgear DG834G running firmware v5.03.16

Comment: What do you have Apache listening on? Is it perhaps only listening on the loopback address, rather than all addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you correctly NAT from the Netgear to your LAN IP, but then you talk about connecting to apache through `loopback`, so i'm assuming `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Easily the problem is that apache then listens **only on the `loopback` interface**. IIRC default apache windows installs don't automatically listen on *all IPs*, but just on `127.0.0.1`.

You should take a look at the [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive and configure it with your LAN IP.